# Unity WaitForSeconds Delay not Functioning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a rhythm game and and working on a script that spawns an object on every beat of a song. Thus, it spawns a single object, waits for the length of the beat, and then spawns the next one. It's supposed to do this until the song finishes. The issue is that the script seems to be spawning everyone of the objects at once, rather than waiting for the specified amount of time. The script compiles fine and I can't figure out what the issue is. Here's my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class spawnState : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float waitTime = 0.483870968f;
    public bool running = true;
    public int beats = 504;
    private int count = 0;

    public GameObject spawn;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Generate object

        while (running == true)
        {

            //Wait
            StartCoroutine(Wait());

            //Count & Stop
            count += 1;
            if (count >= beats)
            {
                running = false;
            }

        }
    }

    //Wait function
    IEnumerator Wait()
    {
        //Wait
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

        //Spawn
        Instantiate(spawn, transform.position, spawn.transform.rotation);

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This must be the 3rd such question with a `StartCoroutine` (usually inside a `while`) in the `Update()` method in so many weeks.   Is everyone from the same lab or something?

Answer (score 0):

For starters **you don't want any possibly blocking `while` loop within `Update`!**

`Update` is called once every frame.

Do you really want to instantiate `504` objects within one frame?

And then `StartCoroutine` does **not** delay the method which calls it. It rather registers a Coroutine to be running and continues immediately with the rest of the code. So you are starting 504 "parallel" running Coroutines and after `0.48..` seconds you suddenly get all 504 objects instantiated at the same time.

---

What you rather want to do would e.g. be either directly using a timer field without a Coroutine

```
private float timer;

void Update()
{
    if(!running) return;

    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if(timer >= waitTime)
    {
        timer = 0;

        Instantiate(spawn, transform.position, spawn.transform.rotation);

        count += 1;
        if (count >= beats)
        {
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you want to use a Coroutine you could e.g. simply do

```
private void Start ()
{
    StartCorouine (SpawnRoutine());
}

private IEnumerator SpawnRoutine ()
{
    for(var count = 0; count < beats; count++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);

        Instantiate(spawn, transform.position, spawn.transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

or if `Start` is anyway the only place where you trigger this it can be that routine itself

```
private IEnumerator Start ()
{
    for(var count = 0; count < beats; count++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);

        Instantiate(spawn, transform.position, spawn.transform.rotation);
    }
}
```